# Getting the record being edited

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I am using a custom validator like as:

```
CustomValidator duplicateValidator;
        duplicateValidator = new CustomValidator()
        {
            @Override
            protected boolean condition(Object value)
            {
                getRecord();
                //* .. code to validate this record here *//
            }
        };
```

But my page gets stuck in a loop, and by using Firebug, it stucks on getRecord(); part, also the getRecord() == null. Is there another way to get the record that I am editing ?

Answer (score 0):

It could not stuck on getRecord method of CustomValidator because it's code is trivial - nothing could go wrong there:

```
/**
 * @return field values for record being validated
 */
public Record getRecord() {
    return record;
}
```

But depending on what you editing you can try to get edited record from that widget by using their specific methods.

For example for DynamicForm:

```
form.getValuesAsRecord()
```

For ListGrid:

```
listGrid.getEditedRecord(listGrid.getEditRow())
```